# c#: Changing Text of 2nd Column in ListView (a.k.a. SubItem)

Tags: c#, listview

I am trying to change the 2nd Column of a ListView on a Win-Form.

I know it's a "Sub-Item", but when I am trying to change the Sub-Item (key = 0) it changes the Text of the very first column.

```
int number = 1;

foreach (ListViewItem existingItem in this.ListViewDokumente.Items) {
    if (existingItem.Group.Name == "ListViewGroupSEE") {
        existingItem.SubItems(0).Text = number.ToString;
        number = number + 1;
    }
}
```

When I change the 0 to 1 in SubItems(0), there's anI get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

How can I change the 2nd Column?

Comment: Shouldn't the 2nd column be this.ListViewDokumente.Items[1] and its text be this.ListViewDokumente.Items[1].Text ??

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my mistake, and here is what was missing:

```
ListViewDokumente.Items.Add(item).SubItems.Add("");
```

The ".Subitems.Add("")" was missing. It needed some "empty spot".

And then, the For Each Loop:

```
int number = 1;

foreach (ListViewItem existingItem in this.ListViewDokumente.Items) {
    if (existingItem.Group.Name == "ListViewGroupSEE") {
        existingItem.SubItems(1).Text = number.ToString;
        number = number + 1;
    }
}
```

It's "SubItems(1)" this time.